# Best approach to implementing [Required] outside MVC, for custom API?

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I'm implementing a API wrapper for a partner's REST service and want to validate some input models. I'm thinking of using the RequiredAttribute since it isn't technically tied to just MVC, and want to run attribute-based validation before sending the request, similar to how MVC's binding pipeline works.

Does anything exist now that will check an object for attached [Required] attributes? Is there an efficient approach? Otherwise I will have to reflect each property and get custom attributes (but was not sure if there's a better approach).  Thanks.

Comment: What about FluentValidation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DataAnnotations you can use Fluent Validation for this.

https://cecilphillip.com/fluent-validation-rules-with-asp-net-core/

https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet

Comment: This is slick and I'll consider this, though this API wrapper will be distributed as a package and I'm trying to reduce the number of dependencies.